# A Bug in MySQLi connect method?

Tags: php, mysqli

This code produces an error:

```
$conn_obj = new MySQLi();
$conn_obj->connect($host, $username, $password);
```

This code works:

```
$conn_obj = new MySQLi($host, $username, $password);
```

My question is: Is this some sort of bug in MySQL, or did I forget to enable some properties?

I know the problem isn't with any of those parameters.

Comment: mysqli_connect — Alias of mysqli::__construct(), so check correct and order of params

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQLi has no method `connect()` when used in an object-oriented manner.  Connections are established through the `__construct()` when calling `new MySQLi($host, $user, $pass, $dbname)`, so this is the expected behavior

See the documentation on [MySQLi::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.connect.php) for complete information.

There is a function `mysqli_connect()`, which establishes a MySQLi connection object in procedural (non-OO) code, as in:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
```

When setting up a MySQLi object via `MySQLi::init()`, you can then call the [`real_connect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.real-connect.php) method on the object returned after setting options.

Adapted from the MySQLi docs:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
if (!$mysqli) {
    die('mysqli_init failed');
}

if (!$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5)) {
    die('Setting MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT failed');
}

if (!$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db')) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: mysqli_connect — Alias of mysqli::__construct() http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php

Comment: @JapanPro See my additions above.  `mysqli_connect()` is different that calling a nonexistent `connect()` method on a MySQLi object.

Comment: It must be a Dreamweaver issue then, because $conn_obj->connect() actually exists as a method in Dreamweaver, but it always results in a false. And I also understand that mysqli_connect() works as a procedural function, but that's another case entirely. Thanks for the clarification.